# Woher kommt "kein Schwein"?

Tags: etymology, idiom

1978 begeisterte Friedrich Karl Wächter sein Publikum mit dem Cartoon "Wahrscheinlich guckt wieder kein Schwein", 1992 Max Raabe das seine (Überschneidungen sind möglich) mit dem Schlager "Kein Schwein ruft mich an". "Kein Schwein" steht als Wendung für "absolut niemand", "keine Menschenseele". Doch warum wird beklagt, dass kein Schwein kommt, wenn man einen Menschen erwartet?

[Im Netz](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~kein%20Schwein%3B%20keine%20Sau&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) findet sich als Erklärung dafür, leider ohne Belege (wie praktisch immer auf populär aufgebauten Internetseiten), der Verweis auf "eine Familie mit Namen Swien" bzw. auf einen Peter Swyn:

> Diese sollen den Schriftverkehr für ihre des Lesens unkundigen
>   Klienten erledigt haben, sodass sich für unleserliche Schriftstücke
>   die Redewendung "das kann nicht einmal ein Swien/Swyn lesen"
>   verbreitet hätte.

Diese Herleitung, die auch Wikipedia und andere Sites übernehmen, ist zwar denkbar, doch man kann auch begründete Einwände dagegen erheben. Erstens wegen des Schriftverkehrs selbst, weil "schlechte" individuelle Handschriften fast nur im privaten Bereich von im Schreiben geübten Menschen vorkamen, der offizielle Schriftverkehr jedoch von professionellen Schreibern abgewickelt wurde. Wahrscheinlicher sind hier Verständnisschwierigkeiten in der Ausdeutung der Texte. Zweitens der sehr punktuellen geografischen und zeitlichen und dadurch offensichtlich zufälligen Lokalisierung einer Dienstleistung wegen, die zweifellos für den gesamten deutschen Sprachraum während der äußerst langen historischen Periode geringer Alphabetisierung charakteristisch war, die erst im Zuge der Aufklärung zum Anlass für bildungspolitische Maßnahmen wurde. Drittens bietet dies zwar eine Erklärung für "kein Schwein", doch um die Variante "keine Sau" zu bilden, bedarf es einer weiteren, korrespondierenden Tradition, die vielleicht älter ist. Die Wendung kommt schließlich nicht nur im Kontext mit "lesen" vor.

Im Prinzip ist die Wendung als übertreibende Erweiterung vorstellbar:

> Niemand und nichts kommt, nicht einmal ein Schwein / eine Sau,

die auch bildlich für ["unsittliche", gering geschätzte Menschen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS21457) stehen konnten. Im Bezug auf das Nicht-lesen-können ist auch ein Zusammenhang mit der metaphorischen Bezeichnung "Schwein/Sau" für [Flecken, Kleckse](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS02366), (Schreib)fehler denkbar, auch wenn ich diesen Zusammenhang quellenmäßig nicht ausweisen kann.

Meine Frage: kennt ihr Nachweise in der (bevorzugt gedruckten) Fachliteratur zur Herkunft der Wendung "kein Schwein" / "keine Sau"?

Comment: Noch ein Link: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Swyn#Sonstiges

Comment: http://www.wdr.de/tv/wissenmachtah/sendungen/01_14.php5

Comment: Auch keine echte Antwort, aber eine [Quelle von 1687](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Anonym/Prosa/Schau-Platz+der+Betrieger/List-+und+lustige+Welthändel/64.+Der+übel-bezahlte+Wirth?hl=kein+schwein): die Wendung ist also schon etwas älter.

Answer (score 7):

Völlig in Vergessenheit geraten ist heute eine alte, andere Bedeutung von [*der Schwein*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS21456#XGS21456) *(maskulin!)*, nämlich die des jungen Menschen, jungen Knechtes, Hirten oder Burschen, von dem sich übrigens auch der englische [Boatswain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boatswain) herleitet<sup>[Goedel](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/39762/39762-h/39762-h.htm)</sup>.

In der sehr alten Wendung *"kein Schwein …"* ist also nicht das Tier, sondern ein junger, unerfahrener (und von daher auch unbedeutender) Mensch gemeint.

Comment: Der erste Absatz ist interessant, der zweite unbelegt.

Comment: Der erste Absatz ist Beleg für die Aussage des zweiten Absatzes, denn sonst hätte ich mir den ersten Absatz sparen können.

Comment: Ich vermute auch, dass es mit dem Gedanken "auch nicht der/die Geringste" etwas zu tun hat, doch ich hoffe noch auf eine explizitere Herleitung.

Answer (score 0):

Es kommt von "Das kann kein Schwein lesen". Und nun wird inflationär "kein Schwein" für jeden Sch... verwendet. Is' halt "cool". :-/

"Das kann kein Schwein lesen" kommt angeblich aus der Schleswiger Gegend.
Natürlich konnten auch alle Pfarrer, Apotheker usw. sehr gut lesen und schreiben! Aber wenn man ein Schriftstück gar nicht lesen/entziffern konnte, ging man zu Herrn Swyn. Und wenn der es nicht mal lesen konnte, dann konnte es kein Swyn lesen.

Swyn/Swin = Schwein

Comment: Ohne Belege erscheint mir das eine sehr schwache Theorie zu sein …